# efficiently replacing many subarrays of 2d array in numpy on large datasets

Tags: arrays, list, performance, numpy, processing-efficiency

Is there a way to speed it up? takes too long on realy large datasets...
"matrice" is a list of numpy arrays with no solid lenght (some could be 1-5 elements longer or shorter)

```
    def replaceScaleBelowZero(arr):  
        if np.amax(arr)<=0:
            arr[arr<=0] = minmax_scale(arr[arr<=0],(min_thresh*0.75,min_thresh)) 
        elif np.min(arr)<=0:
            arr[arr<=0] = minmax_scale(arr[arr<=0],(min_thresh*0.75,min_thresh)) 
        return arr 
    def replaceScaleBelowMinThresh(arr):  
       if np.amax(arr)<min_thresh:
           arr[arr<sl_thresh] = minmax_scale(arr[arr<min_thresh],(min_thresh*0.75,min_thresh)) 
       elif np.min(arr)<min_thresh:  
           arr[arr<min_thresh] = minmax_scale(arr[arr<min_thresh],(min_thresh*0.75,min_thresh)) 
       return arr 

    matrice = [replaceScaleBelowZero(slice_  ) for slice_ in matrice ] 
    matrice = [replaceScaleBelowMinThresh(slice_ ) for slice_ in matrice ]
```

Comment: In first function you can delete `if-elif` and leave only `arr[arr <= 0] = ...`. And how `minmax_scale()` defined?

Comment: @V.Ayrat  minmax_scale() is sklearn's minmaxscaler
"from sklearn.preprocessing import minmax_scale".  I tried "arr[arr <= 0] = ..." But it gave me "ValueError: Found array with 0 sample(s) (shape=(0,)) while a minimum of 1 is required."

Answer (score 0):

`sklearn.preprocessing.minmax_scale` use a lot of checkings. If you rewrite your

```
arr[arr<=0] = minmax_scale(arr[arr<=0],(min_thresh*0.75,min_thresh))
```

as

```
a = arr[arra<=0]
a -= a.min()
a /= a.max()
a *= (0.25 * min_thresh)
a += 0.75 * min_thresh
```

(assuming arr is 1d) it should be faster. If it works I think it can be optimized further with rewriting this -=, /=, *=, += with just two such opertaions.

In your second function you use

```
arr[arr<sl_thresh] = minmax_scale(arr[arr<min_thresh] ...
```

if `sl_thresh != min_thresh` this can give errors. If `sl_thresh = min_thresh` I guess you can drop you `if-else` clause as your `ValueError` likely was raised by `sklearn`.

Comment: Sorry I dont understand this second part:                                                                                  "In your second function you use

    arr[arr<sl_thresh] = minmax_scale(arr[arr<min_thresh] ...

if `sl_thresh != min_thresh` this can give errors. If `sl_thresh = min_thresh` I guess you can drop you `if-else` clause as your `ValueError` likely was raised by `sklearn`."

Comment: Is that correct ?                                                           .                                              ```def minmax_scale_efficient(arr,newmin,newmax):
    a = arr[arr<=0]
    a -= a.min()
    a /= a.max()
    a *= ((newmax-newmin) * min_thresh)
    a += newmin * min_thresh
    return a       ```

Comment: I mean for example if `a = np.arange(3); a[a < 0] = a[a < 2]` you  get error because the left hand side and rhs have different sizes. The same for you code if `sl_thresh != min_thresh` it can give errors. So I guess that `sl_thresh` should be changed to `min_thresh` in your code?

Comment: I hope that it is correct. But you should check it on you data. And check is it really faster. If speed is important you better embed `minmax_scale_efficient` in you code as calling function also take some time.